# Connection does NOT display Action

Tags: swift, xcode

When I ctrl-drag from a `UIButton` in storyboard to the viewcontroller class, 
 Xcode is not showing the option to create an IBAction.

I have already tried to start a new project and it still does not have the Connect: Action option available.

Comment: Make sure that the class to which you are trying to drag the outlet is the View's controller

Comment: What @JobinsJohn asks you to check is correct. Also, I've seen this behavior *even when* the correct VC is set in IB. While I honestly do not know why it happens, I've seen two things: First, what *does* the code view have for code? Please, if the VC is set correctly show us this. Second, try closing/reopening Xcode. For me, that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps :-

1. Open `storyboard` and `yourViewController` side by side after clicking on Assistant Editor.

[image]

2. Now Drag and Drop from `UIButton` to `class` file. It will open one popup menu.

[image]

3. Now click on **connection** it will open option menu with **Outlet, Action, Outlet Connection**.

[image]

4. Now click on **Action**. It will set within the same popup menu, and ask for method name. Here you have to add your **Method Name**, and click on connect button.

[image]

5. At the last point you will find your method within your class, with `@IBAction` connection.

[image]

Hope above steps is useful for you.

Comment: The step 3 is not displaying Acionfor me. That is the problem

Comment: Confirm that storyboard class which contains `UIButton` and in assistant editor is the same class or different? Inshort check your storyboard class and .swift class. Both are same or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the ViewController cocoa class is correctly connected to the ViewController in the Interface builder, then,try with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37322981/8038084.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, even restarting and cleaning does not help me. What I do is **make it the other way round**.

Create an `IBAction` manually in your code.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed() {
    [...]
}
```

The function should appear inside your IB under **Connections inspector/Received Actions**...

[image: Connections inspector/Received Actions]

where you can simply **connect it** to your button/gesture recognizer etc.

[image: list of control events]